# Google app engine: Golang datastore.GetAll() not working

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

Once a week a cron job calls the following function in one of my app engine projects:

```
func cleanMealsFromDatabase(context appengine.Context) error {
    query := datastore.NewQuery("Essen").Limit(1000).KeysOnly()
    keys, err := query.GetAll(context, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return datastore.DeleteMulti(context, keys)
}
```

I'm trying to batch delete a bunch of datastore entities. The function gets called correctly, but

```
query.GetAll(context, nil)
```

seems to always return an error. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: And what is that error that it returns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I now know what went wrong. When I finally figured out how to log an error in app engine, it said:

```
API error 1 (datastore_v3: BAD_REQUEST): cannot write more than 500 entities in a single call
```

So all I had to do, was to change the *Limit* parameter from **1000** to **500** like this:

```
query := datastore.NewQuery("Essen").Limit(500).KeysOnly()
```

Now it works like intended.